# Discover huge page support on POSIX or Linux

Tags: linux, posix, virtual-memory, huge-pages

I'm working on a program which needs to detect at runtime whether the system it's running on supports hugepages, and if so, what sizes are available. Ideally I'd like this to work for any POSIX platform, but a Linux-specific solution would be a start.

POSIX supports [`sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) to get the default page size on the platform, but doesn't seem to similarly support asking for any hugepage sizes. I could also potentially check by trying to [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) `MAP_HUGE_2MB` or `MAP_HUGE_1GB` arguments, but that would be slow, and in the case of 1GB huge pages, incredibly wasteful (and it could easily fail due to a lack of available memory).

Comment: Maybe Linux only, but `madvise` has `MADV_HUGEPAGE` that may help. It also has the file path `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/` that gives information. This article may also help you: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/46111

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, as a programmer, you probably want to make use of the `libhugetlbfs` which takes care of everything for you under the hood. (Note: It may not even be required, I do not know for sure, I still have to test).

It replaces all the functions that manage memory with its own version which will automatically switch to a huge page if/when possible. This will include `malloc()` and `mmap()` and others like `fork()` allocating a stack.

With Ubuntu, you can install the library this way:

```
sudo apt-get install libhugetlbfs-dev
```

You can then make use of functions such as [`get_huge_pages()`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libhugetlbfs-dev/get_huge_pages.3.en.html) if you definitely want to allocate a large buffer in a huge page. This is an equivalent to `malloc()`. With the library installed you should have the manual pages so for details you can do:

```
man get_huge_page
```

There is also an OS function, [`mincore()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html), which allows you to get the number of huge pages and small (4K) pages used by a region of memory. There is a sample using in the BSD code below (where the function comes from, it's a BSD thing). This is most certainly what you were looking for under Unices (although it may not be available on all Unix OSes, like IRIX, HP-UX, AIX... you'd have to check). Note that this function is always available. You do not need the `libhugetlbfs` library to use it. Note that under Linux it doesn't look like they set anything else than bit 0, meaning that you only know whether the page is resident or not and not the size of the page as in BSD.

I pretty much exclusively work under Linux. But for MS-Windows, this is called "Large Pages". They have docs here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/large-page-support

Finally the various BSD implementations call those "Super Pages" (macos therefore uses that interface). I found [this page](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2015-June/056067.html) with a code sample showing how many super pages get used for a large `malloc()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        size_t size, flags, i, super = 0, ordinary = 0;
        void *addr;
        char *vec;

        if (argc != 2)
                return (0);

        size = atoi(argv[1]);
        addr = malloc(size);
        vec = malloc(size / 4096);

        memset(addr, 0, size);

        flags = mincore(addr, size, vec);

        printf("addr %p len %d:\n", addr, size);
        for (i = 0; i <= size / 4096; i++)
                if (vec[i] & MINCORE_SUPER)
                        super++;
                else
                        ordinary++;
        printf("%d 4K blocks super-mapped, %d ordinary 4K pages\n",
            super, ordinary);

        return (0);
}
```

And some output of that FreeBSD code:

> x23% ./a.out 1000000
> addr 0x801006000 len 1000000:
> 0 4K blocks super-mapped, 245 ordinary 4K pages
>
> x23% ./a.out 10000000
> addr 0x801000000 len 10000000:
> 2048 4K blocks super-mapped, 394 ordinary 4K pages
>
> x23% ./a.out 100000000000
> addr 0x801000000 len 1215752192:
> 296448 4K blocks super-mapped, 367 ordinary 4K pages

As we can see, the first number represents "super mapped pages", meaning that it uses memory allocated in blocks of 2Mb or 1Gb or some other sizes depending on your OS and settings and it was automatically handled under the hood.

**IMPORTANT:** The `memset()` is important, it commits ALL the pages of the allocated memory. Without that call, the allocated pages may be 1 or 2...

Answer (score 0):

**Linux**

Parse the contents of `/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages` ([which is what `libhugetlbfs` does](https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs/blob/6b126a4d7da9490fa40fe7e1b962edcb939feddc/hugeutils.c#L765):

```
[~]# ls -l /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Dec 30 16:38 hugepages-1048576kB
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Dec 30 16:38 hugepages-2048kB
[~]#
```

In C (headers and error checking omitted for clarity):

```
// 16 should be plenty for this example (should really do this dynamically)
int size_count = 1;

// use unsigned long long to match strtoull()
unsigned long long page_sizes[ 16 ];

// get the base page size
page_sizes[ 0 ] = sysconf( _SC_PAGESIZE );

// now get the huge page size(s)
DIR *dirp = opendir( "/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages" );
for ( ;; )
{
    struct dirent *dirent = readdir( dirp );
    if ( NULL == dirent ) break;

    if ( '.' == dirent->d_name[ 0 ] ) continue;

    char *p = strchr( dirent->d_name, '-' );
    if ( NULL == p ) continue;

    page_sizes[ size_count++ ] = 1024ULL * strtoull( p + 1, NULL, 0 ); 
}

closedir( dirp );
```

If you have `libhugetlbfs-dev` installed:

```
#include <hugetlbfs.h>

int size_count = getpagesizes( NULL, 0 );

long page_sizes[ size_count ];

getpagesizes( page_sizes, size_count );
```

Link with -lhugetlbfs

**Solaris**

In C, use [the `getpagesizes()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37843/getpagesizes-3c.html):

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

int size_count = getpagesizes( NULL, 0 );

size_t page_sizes[ size_count ];

getpagesizes( page_sizes, size_count );
```

**FreeBSD**

FreeBSD copied [the `getpagesizes()` function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getpagesizes&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) from Solaris 9:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

int size_count = getpagesizes( NULL, 0 );

size_t page_sizes[ size_count ];

getpagesizes( page_sizes, size_count );
```